# Saving pie chart as an image using database data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts

Require some help when trying to save chart as an image. Sorry just started this new chart.js.

Issue:

1. How do I add my database data inside the chart? I keep try to add in $user but it keep giving me undefined user.

Here is the data that I want to add in from my database,

```
  $users = DB::table('personal_infos')
      ->join('evaluations','evaluations.user_id', '=', 'personal_infos.id') 
      ->select('evaluations.recommendation','evaluations.created_at' ) 
      ->where('evaluations.recommendation', '=', 'Yes')  
      ->get();
```

For now I just used something like this to generate the pie chart:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $("#save-btn").click(function() {
        $("#canvas").get(0).toBlob(function(blob) {
            saveAs(blob, "chart_1.png");
        });
});

var data = [
    {
        value: 300,
        color:"#F7464A",
        highlight: "#FF5A5E",
        label: "Red"
    },
    {
        value: 50,
        color: "#46BFBD",
        highlight: "#5AD3D1",
        label: "Green"
    },
    {
        value: 100,
        color: "#FDB45C",
        highlight: "#FFC870",
        label: "Yellow"
    }
];

var ctx = $("#canvas").get(0).getContext("2d");
var mychart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data,
{
    //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
    segmentShowStroke : false,

    //String - The colour of each segment stroke
    segmentStrokeColor : "#fff",

    //Number - The width of each segment stroke
    segmentStrokeWidth : 2,

    //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
    percentageInnerCutout : 0, // This is 0 for Pie charts

    //Number - Amount of animation steps
    animationSteps : 10,

    //String - Animation easing effect
    animationEasing : "linear",

    //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
    animateRotate : true,

    //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
    animateScale : false,

    //String - A legend template
    legendTemplate : "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>"

}
);
        </script>
```

Comment: Try using this https://github.com/julles/laravel-highcharts